# In nltk wordnet, wn.synsets.definition(lang="lang") show enlish and japanese, but not other languages

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

`wn.synsets.definition(lang="lang")` show english and japanese result, but not other languages.

`wn.synset('word').lemma_names` shows the other languages too, though.

Do I need extra download? , there is the difference between languages?

[image]

[image]

the documents says that it do lazy download. so I tried a few times, but result didn't change.

Answer (score 2):

I played around a bit and the first thing I found out is that definitions are available for more languages than just English and Japanese. See the following table for definitions of a few words including your example word for all the languages available from `wn.langs()` after downloading nltk `omw-1.4`. 'dog' has definitions in 7 languages, 'house' in 9, and 'person' in 11.

Regarding the missing definitions for certain languages, I think the data just isn't present in the corresponding wordnets. The [NLTK wordnet documentation](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html) states:

> This module also allows you to find lemmas in languages other than English from the Open Multilingual Wordnet (https://omwn.org/)

If you go to https://omwn.org/ and follow the links for the respective wordnets, you'll find for example [this page](https://multiwordnet.fbk.eu/online/multiwordnet.php) where you can search for words in a few languages. Searching 'casa' in Spanish, you'll find the definition reverts to the English definition for 'house', but for Italian there is a definition in Italian - which is consistent with the table below.

Hope this helps!

| lang | dog | house | person |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| eng | a member of the genus Canis (probably descended from the common wolf) that has been domesticated by man since prehistoric times; occurs in many breeds | a dwelling that serves as living quarters for one or more families | a human being |
| als |  | Ndërtesë për të banuar (zakonisht për një familje a për familje të një gjaku); banesë; apartament ku banon një familje. | të qënurit njeri |
| arb |  |  |  |
| bul | Вид домашно животно от семейство хищни бозайници, с различна големина, цвят на козината и различни породи, което лае и често се използва като пазач на дома и имота, за лов, може да бъде дресирано и обучавано за различни служебни цели. | Сграда,помещение за постоянно живеене на отделно семейство или човек. | Отделен човек, който със своите неповторими качества се отличава, различава от другите хора. |
| cmn |  |  |  |
| dan |  |  |  |
| ell | σκύλος του γένους Canis familiaris που συνήθως προέρχεται από τον κοινό λύκο και έχει εξημερωθεί από τους προϊστορικούς χρόνους | το τμήμα οικήματος (λ .χ. το διαμέρισμα πολυκατοικίας) στο οποίο διαμένει κανείς | το έμβιο ον, κάθε άτομο, άνθρωπος ανεξαρτήτως φύλου και ηλικίας |
| fin |  |  |  |
| fra |  |  |  |
| heb |  | מבנה המשמש כמקום מגורים למשפחה אחת או יותר | מישהו דופק בדלת |
| hrv |  |  |  |
| isl |  |  |  |
| ita | mammifero domestico dei canidi, molto comune, diffuso in tutto il mondo, con attitudini varie a seconda della razza | edificio destinato ad abitazione | entità umana considerata in quanto tale, senza caratterizzazioni di sesso, età, provenienza, ecc. |
| ita_iwn | animale domestico molto comune, diffuso in tutto il mondo, usato per la caccia, la difesa, nella pastorizia, e come animale da compagnia |  | essere distinto da ogni altro della medesima specie |
| jpn | 有史以前から人間に家畜化されて来た（おそらく普通のオオカミを先祖とする）イヌ属の動物 | 1家族以上のための居住棟として機能する住居 | 一人の人間 |
| cat |  |  |  |
| eus |  |  |  |
| glg |  |  |  |
| spa |  |  |  |
| ind |  |  | seseorang yang dipandang tinggi |
| zsm |  |  |  |
| nld |  |  |  |
| nno |  |  |  |
| nob |  |  |  |
| pol |  |  |  |
| por |  |  |  |
| ron | Animal mamifer carnivor domesticit, folosit pentru pază, vânătoare etc.. | construcție destinată pentru a servi de locuință uneia sau mai multor familii | Individ al speciei umane, om considerat prin totalitatea însușirilor sale fizice și psihice |
| lit |  |  |  |
| slk |  |  |  |
| slv |  |  |  |
| swe |  |  |  |
| tha |  |  |  |
| total | 7 | 9 | 11 |

---

Code used to generate the above table (in Google Colab):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')

import pandas as pd
defs = pd.DataFrame()
for lang in wn.langs():
    for word in ['dog', 'house', 'person']:
        this_word = {}
        def_ = wn.synsets(word)[0].definition(lang=lang)
        defs.at[lang, word] = def_[0] if isinstance(def_, list) else def_
        defs[word] = defs[word].astype('object')
for word in defs.columns:
    defs_present = len([def_ for def_ in defs[word].to_list() if def_ != None])
    defs.at['total', word] = defs_present
defs
```